# Is Ruby's length method a symbol? Why is :length sometimes the same as length?

Tags: ruby, alias, symbols

I came across the following while reading about how easy it is to redefine methods in Ruby:

```
class Array
  alias :old_length :length
  def length
    old_length / 2
  end
end
puts [1, 2, 3].length
```

Sure, it's a bad idea, but it makes the point. But it bothered me that we switch between `:length` and `length` and `:old_length` and `old_length` so easily. So I tried it this way:

```
class Array
  alias old_length length
  def length
    old_length / 2
  end
end
puts [1, 2, 3].length
```

It works just fine - apparently just like the first version. I feel like there's something obvious that I'm missing, but I'm not sure what it is.

So, in a nuthsell, why are `:name` and `name` interchangeable in these cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A method isn't a symbol, but its name is. Just writing `length` calls the method `length`. To specify the *name of the method* rather than perform the method, you use a symbol.

```
class Array
  def show_the_difference
    puts length
    puts :length
  end
end

['three', 'items', 'here'].show_the_difference
# prints "3" for the first puts and then "length" for the second
```

The case you found with `alias` is an exception, just because `alias` works differently from everything else in the language.

Comment: Perfect: that helps a lot, and it's not _so_ obvious that I feel bad for not knowing it already.

Answer (score 3):

`alias` is a primitive that gets special handling, and apparently can take both symbols and bare names.  The related `alias_method` is just an ordinary method, and has to use ordinary syntax.

```
alias_method :old_length, :length
```